# MySQL query to select all results from table 2 that match table 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have pages stored in the database, and another table that stores translations of that same page:

Table page_pages:

```
ID    Title        Content
1     First Page   Stuff...
2     Second Page  More stuff...
```

Table page_translations:

```
ID    PageID    LanguageID    Title             Content
1     1         2             Primero pagina    Cosas...
```

So, right now I am querying the `page_pages` table to get the page information:

```
$query = SELECT * FROM page_pages WHERE ID = 1
```

How do I adjust this query to select translations that exist with the `PageID` AS `Translations`, and have that be it's own array with the `LanguageID` as the array keys?

This way, I can check if a translation exists like:

```
$language_id = 1;

if (isset($query['Translations'][$language_id])) {
  echo $query['Translations'][$language_id]['Title'];

} else {
  echo $query['Title'];
}
```

Comment: what result you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use MySQL's `group_concat` function with 'left join', e.g.:

```
SELECT
    pp.id,
    pp.title,
    pp.content,
    group_concat(pl.language_id) AS languages
FROM
    page_pages pp
LEFT JOIN page_translations pl ON pp.id = pl.pageID
WHERE
    pp.id = 1
GROUP BY
    pp.id;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5014f9/2/0)**.

Comment: Thank you. I would never have been able to come up with that on my own